# Trying to run App in Android studio 1.4.1 and having build problems

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

Go to run my app and i get the following errors in the log.

Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'.

Log states the following "Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'.
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

Would anyone kindly tell me how to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for you

option 1-update the gradle:

i-Get latest version supported by Android Studio from: http://www.gradle.org/downloads

ii-Extract the gradle file and install to dists folder(gradle folder): default location is: C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

iii-Open Android Studio: File/Settings/Gradle/Service directory path: (Change to folder you set above) and Click ok.

iv-restart Android Studio.

Option 2-Delete the .gradle folder:

default location is:

C:\Users[username]\gradle\wrapper\dists

after that open Android Studio and make a new project (might need to restart).

Comment: Thanks that worked but i am now getting this message as an error Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Comment: Right click on your project -> open module settings-> Go to "Dependencies" tab -> you'll find "junit:junit:4.12" -> select it and right click and choose remove option -> ok

Now again try to build your application.